# React native: Build one apk for all android devices

Tags: android, react-native

I make a android app with react native and after build `aab` and published in google play, now i want download apk to upload to othet store, but google play install special apk for ever android phone, how cat in download full apk to upload in other store for all android phones?

Comment: When you generate the APK file for release (with Android Studio for example) it should be a local file on your machine. You can upload this APK to any distribution service that will accept them. Check the `/android/app/release` folder of your RN project for the APK

Comment: can you not build apk from your code?

Comment: generated apk but not installing on android and i getting android protection error @scgough

Comment: Do you mean a `Play Protection Error`? If so go here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/protectappeals

Comment: You can use bundletool. https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool

Answer (score 0):

In the android folder execute this command:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

and in the app/build folder you could find the .apk